# PHP Regex match increment ids with optional spaces

Tags: php, regex

Trying to find increments in strings like intended purpose (banking) ect.

I try to create a regex that matches `123456 ...` and `123 456 ...`.

I receive the intended purpose lines imploded without empty space.
So i will get the increment like
`FooBar 123456 Baz`
`FooBar 123456Baz`
or `FooBar123456Baz`.

The increments start with 15 or 16.
Examples: `150000000001` `160000000001`.

**What i got:** `(^\s*|[^0-9])((15|16)(?:\d\s?){10})([^0-9]|\s*$)`

```
Pattern break down:
#

// Begin of string (perhaps empty spaces) OR no digit.
(^\s*|[^0-9])

// Prefix "15" or "16" and 10 digits (perhaps empty spaces between).
((15|16)(?:\d\s?){10})
                      
// Not following by digit OR (perhaps empty spaces between) end of string.
([^0-9]|\s*$)
                      
#
```

First problem i have is that `(?:\d\s?)` always selects an empty space after.
Second problem is that my attempts on the beginning and the end do not really work.

The main part is `((15|16)(?:\d\s?){10})`.
But this also continues to select after line breaks, which it should not.
That is why i try to limit the matches with the "not 0-9 OR end|start of line".

*Im testing this at regex101.com*

Examples what it **should match**:

```
-- no empty space at start of line, and one or more spaces between, and none-number before|after
150000000001 150000000001  150000000001 150000000001 d 150000000001d 150000000001 d150000000001d

-- empty space before and in between
 150 000 000 001
 15 00 00 00 00 01 --not a must tho
150000000001    -- just a string of the increment only
160000000001    -- just a string of the increment only
```

The **new line problem** -

```
-- the new line problem
Foo Bar160000000
001 Baz
```

selects

```
160000000
001
```

which it should not.

How to i proper restrict the beginning and the end?

*Thank you for your time.*

Comment: Try `/(?<!\d)1[56]\d(?:\s?\d){9}(?!\d)/` or - if your matches cannot span across lines at all - `/(?<!\d)1[56]\d(?:\h?\d){9}(?!\d)/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Works, except for the new line problem.

Comment: Check the second one.

Comment: Second works. NICE. Can you explain this in a post, so i can accept it?
I think those are negative and positive lookups behind and before, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
/(?<!\d)1[56]\d(?:\h?\d){9}(?!\d)/
```

The regex matches:

- `(?<!\d)` - a left-hand digit boundary, no digit is allowed immediately on the left
- `1` - a `1` char
- `[56]` - a `5` or `6` char
- `\d` - any digit
- `(?:\h?\d){9}` - nine occurrences of an optional horizontal whitespace and any one digit
- `(?!\d)` - a right-hand digit boundary, no digit is allowed immediately on the right.